# Android soft keyboard dynamically change input layout

Tags: android, layout, input, keyboard

In my app the user is able to search for a room in a building of my universities campus via an AutoCompleteTextView.

95% of the rooms have "numbers" like "007" (digits only) but there are also some rooms with "numbers" like "007a". So the user has to have the chance to input **Strings**, not only numbers.

What I want is this: the user clicks the AutoCompleteTextView and the initial keyboard should display the **numberpad**, but with the option to switch to the layout for typing letters.

How could I accomplish that? (didn't find anything useful so far...)
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. I haven't solved it completely but you may get some ideas from [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542983/how-to-know-if-the-keyboard-layout-changes-between-numbers-and-letters). I have placed a button beside the EditText that switches the InputType of the EditText between InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER and InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT.